# /proc/bus/usb in /etc/fstab prevents my PC to start the graphic session

Tags: fstab, ups

I bought a UPS this week and it came with the WinPower software that lets my PC (Linux Mint 18 XFCE) to communicate with the UPS, monitor it, and receive a shutdown signal in case the UPS battery is very low.

The issue is that the software added the following line to my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
usbfs    /proc/bus/usb    usbfs    defaults  0  0
```

Once I restart the PC it shows a message in console saying that there is a problem, that I must execute `journalctl -xb`, it request my root password and it says that I can execute `systemctl default` or `systemctl reboot`, none of both systemctl commands fix the issue, and I don't understand the output of journalctl command.

Once I go to `/etc/fstab` and comment the `/proc/bus/usb` line I can reboot normally to my graphic environment.

I have almost zero knowledge about fstab so I don't know what all those paramenters affect the system nor how can I modify that line to keep the software and my graphic environment working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `usbfs` (USB filesystem) was removed completely from the kernel in kernel version 3.5. Similar files are available under `/dev/bus/usb` and `/sys/bus/usb`.

You will need a newer version of the WinPower software that works with more recent kernels. Maybe try the one available from [their website](http://www.ups-software-download.com/).

Comment: Oh, thank you. Actually the CD had version 4.7.0.0 and the installer didn't work, so I downloaded the newest version available from the website (5.0.0.0). So I guess it simply doesn't work. Actually after I commented that line the graphic environment is working and the UPS monitor is working too, but I thought that something would be missing if I leave that line commented in /etc/fstab... but now I can sleep again... lol